# Mapbox 1.6 - Javascript error with Marker layer (GeoJSON)

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, mapbox

I am having 2 issues that I'm hoping someone can help me with.

1) Marker layer renders (GeoJSON), but sometimes renders before the actually map loads, need to implement a wait on ready, but not sure how to.
2) Getting this error on heroku: TypeError: Argument 1 of Node.appendChild does not implement interface Node, and I can't select the actual marker, while this works fine on my development laptop.

Thanks!

```
TypeError: Argument 1 of Node.appendChild does not implement interface Node

<meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no' />
<script src='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/v1.6.2/mapbox.js'></script>
<link href='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/v1.6.2/mapbox.css' rel='stylesheet' />

<div id="map" style="width: 600px; height: 400px"></div>

<style>
#open-popup {
    position:absolute;
    top:5px;
    right:5px;
}
</style>
<div id='map'></div>
<button id='open-popup'>open popup</button>

<script>
var doctor = <%=raw @hash_product.to_json %>;
var map = L.mapbox.map('map', 'secret')
   .setView([doctor.lat, doctor.lng], 9);


$.ajax({
 dataType: 'json',
 url: product.id + '.json',
 success: function(data) {
   map.markerLayer.setGeoJSON(data);
 }
});

map.markerLayer.on('layeradd', function(e) {
 var feature, marker, popupContent;
 marker = e.layer;
 properties = marker.feature.properties;
 if (properties.name || properties.address){
   popupContent = '<div class="popup">' + '<h3>' + properties.name + '</h3>' + '<p>' + properties.address + '</p>' + '</div>';    
   return marker.bindPopup(popupContent, {
     closeButton: false,
     minWidth: 320
   });    
 }
});


$('article li').click(function(e) {
 var current, currentlyClickedName;
 current = $(this);
 currentlyClickedName = current.find('h2').text();
 return map.markerLayer.eachLayer(function(layer) {
   var id;
   if (layer.feature.properties.name === currentlyClickedName) {
     id = layer._leaflet_id;
     return map._layers[id].openPopup();
   }
 });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Please provide a link to a working copy, or this source after it is generated by Ruby on Rails: any number of things could be coming out of the 'doctor' variable.

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding an event listener to the map 'load' event and setting the View after you set up the map, but before you setView:

```
    var map = L.mapbox.map('map', 'secret');
    map.on('load', function () {
       $.ajax({
        dataType: 'json',
        url: product.id + '.json',
        success: function(data) {
          map.markerLayer.setGeoJSON(data);
         }
       });
    });
    map.setView([doctor.lat, doctor.lng], 9);
```

This should take care of the first problem. The onLoad will execute the ajax call after the setView.

As for the second problem. I'm also searching for an answer, will keep you updated

**Update**
The problem is with the .bindPopup method.
So for me the problem was in having an outdated version of leaflet. In the older leaflet. You could only pass and HTML element (object) a string or a HTML string. In the new Leaflet you can also pass an instance of a Popup.

I'm not sure what the rest of your application does or how MapBox' Leaflet version works, nor do I know what version of Leaflet is running in the Mapbox version on heroku, but you can try checking if the popup is bound e.g.:

```
 if (layer.feature.properties.name === currentlyClickedName) {
  id = layer._leaflet_id;
  if (map._layers[id].getProperty() !== undefined) {
   return map._layers[id].openPopup();
  }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks! very helpful. I ditched the javascript code and pushed the geojson lay straight to mapbox. Mapbox renders the pins and allows the pushpins to be click-able. The geojson object has to have the attributes of name: and properties:

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this problem with a much simpler line of javascript.
I erased the above javascript and used mapbox's built in push-pin ability.
Works pretty much the way it is supposed too.

```
<script>
var doctor = <%=raw @hash_productloc.to_json %>;
var map = L.mapbox.map('map', 'you map').setView([productloc.lat, productloc.lng], 9)
var featureLayer = L.mapbox.featureLayer()
     .loadURL(product.id + '.json')
     .addTo(map);
</script>
```